# Pass a database value into a select with ajax and php

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

i want to get data from the db and show them into a dropdown. So when i click on the option it shoud give me the results from that database. So if I add a new entry manually in the database, my select option should grow bigger automatically.

Here is my Code:
index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script>
            function showUser(str) {
                if (str == "") {
                    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
                    return;
                } else {
                    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                        }
                    };
                    xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
                    xmlhttp.send();
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
<body>

<form>
    <select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
        <option value="">Select a person:</option>
        <option value="1">here should be opt1 from db</option>
        <option value="2">here should be opt1 from db</option>
        <option value="3">here should be opt1 from db</option>
        <option value="4">here should be opt1 from db</option>
    </select>
</form>
<br>
<div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here...</b></div>

</body>
</html>
```

getuser.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        table {
            width: 100%;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }

        table, td, th {
            border: 1px solid black;
            padding: 5px;
        }

        th {text-align: left;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','ajax');
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

mysqli_select_db($con,"ajax");
$sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '".$q."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

echo "<table>
<tr>
<th>Vorname</th>
<th>Nachname</th>
<th>Alter</th>
<th>Stadt</th>
<th>Job</th>
</tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['vorname'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['nachname'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['r_alter'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['stadt'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['job'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);


?>
</body>
</html>
```

I need to change the code so that the select field (when starting) is dynamically filled with the current values ​​from the database.

I hope that you could help me with it...

Thank you!

Comment: Please go read [ask]. If you want to ask for our help, then you need to be _specific_ as to what you actually need help with. You apparently already know how to select stuff from the database, and how to then loop over the resulting records. So where exactly is your problem now, to do that to a) select the data you need, and then b) create option elements out of that data, in a loop?

Answer (score 0):

The way I understood your question:

JavaScript: Add this script just before the `</body>` tag.

```js
functionForSelectOptionToGrowBigger(){
    $.ajax ({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'selectlist.php',
        success: function(result){ 
            $("#growBigger").html(result);
        } 
    });
}

$( document ).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function(){
        functionForSelectOptionToGrowBigger();
    }, 3000); // 3 seconds
});
```

HTML: Add `id="growBigger"`

```html
<form>
    <div id="growBigger">
        <select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
            <option value="">Select a person:</option>
            <option value="1">here should be opt1 from db</option>
            <option value="2">here should be opt1 from db</option>
            <option value="3">here should be opt1 from db</option>
            <option value="4">here should be opt1 from db</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</form>
```

Now create `selectlist.php` and fetch data inside a select option with your php code. After that refresh the page and your dropdown will automatically regenerated after every 3 seconds. And you can add options manually in your DB.